# File creation without creating new folder [confusion] from user-input

Tags: java, file, io, user-controls, user-input

Lets say we have a user who wants a file named:
"test/lasdhjal.txt", whatever. Now if I put this into a new File(input); object inside, it will think that test/ is a folder, whilst it's a part of the name. What can I do against that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the limitation of not allowing a "/" in a file name is imposed at the kernel level, this is not something you can get around.

Comment: How can some OS handle that then?

Comment: My understanding is that none of them do.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/719916/how-to-have-a-forward-slash-in-a-file-name

Comment: You sure? E.g. you can create in windows a folder with a / in it's name. Also for example Minecraft has used to be a file structure, which sometimes included / iirc

Comment: 100% sure. Here's a link to a wikepedia list of characters forbidden from windows filenames: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words